# Is there a way to specify a pane of an FXML file?

Tags: java, javafx, arraylist, fxml

This is my problem, I have a method that loads information from an ArrayList to a specific pane:

```
public void LoadData(Pane pane, String fxid, int noAtm) {
    // Pane pane = (Pane) loader.getNamespace().get(fxid);
    
    Label simbolo = (Label) pane.lookup("#Simbolo" + fxid);
    Label atmass = (Label) pane.lookup("#MasaAtomica" + fxid);
    Label numOx = (Label) pane.lookup("#NumOx" + fxid);
    Label nombre = (Label) pane.lookup("#Nom" + fxid);
    Label numAtm = (Label) pane.lookup("#NumAtm" + fxid);
    
    for (Datos d : datosList) {
        if (d.getNumeroAtomico() == noAtm) {
            simbolo.setText(d.getSimbolo());
            atmass.setText(Double.toString(d.getMasaAtomica()));
            numOx.setText(d.getNumeroOxidacion());
            nombre.setText(d.getNombre());
            numAtm.setText(Integer.toString(d.getNumeroAtomico()));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This works, but I don't know how to specify the pane that will be used from the FXML file

```
@FXML
private void handleMouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {
    Pane pane = (Pane) event.getSource();//crea una varibale local basada en el pane
    String id = pane.getId(); // obtiene el id basado en el pane
    Datos dummy = new Datos (null, null, 0, 0, null); 
    dummy.LoadData(pane, id, 3);
}
```

All good so far, but I need the LoadData method to be able to work without the need for the mouse event. I tried to make a method that creates a local pane, assign as fxid the one from which you will work and then call the method passing the local pane as argument, but it returns an error and I think it is because when said method is created it is a separate pane from the one of the FXML file.

This is the method:

```
private void charge(String id) {
    Pane pane = new Pane();
    pane.setId(id);
    Datos dummy2 = new Datos (null, null, 0, 0, null);
    dummy2.LoadData(pane, id, 3);
}
```

```
public void LoadData( String fxid, int noAtm) {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Escena.fxml"));
   Pane pane = (Pane) loader.getNamespace().get(fxid);
    
    Label simbolo = (Label) pane.lookup("#Simbolo" + fxid);
    Label atmass = (Label) pane.lookup("#MasaAtomica" + fxid);
    Label numOx = (Label) pane.lookup("#NumOx" + fxid);
    Label nombre = (Label) pane.lookup("#Nom" + fxid);
    Label numAtm = (Label) pane.lookup("#NumAtm" + fxid);
    
    for (Datos d : datosList) {
        if (d.getNumeroAtomico() == noAtm) {
            simbolo.setText(d.getSimbolo());
            atmass.setText(Double.toString(d.getMasaAtomica()));
            numOx.setText(d.getNumeroOxidacion());
            nombre.setText(d.getNombre());
            numAtm.setText(Integer.toString(d.getNumeroAtomico()));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error that is generated when calling the method in those ways: I only know that it mentions that the pane is empty, at other times it mentioned that the labels are.
So, if anyone knows the way to create a pane based on the one in the FXML file and do it with the help of the fxid, please tell me how to do it.

Comment: I don’t understand why you are doing all of these lookups. You can inject references into your controller, using `fx:id` in the fxml and [`@FXML` in the controller](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#fxml_annotation).  Any reasonable FXML tutorial will demonstrate that.  The technique works no matter the node type. So it will work for both your labels and panes.  If you have an issue, provide a [mcve].

Comment: A weird thing about your code is that you don’t even call `load` on the controller.  Instead you get the namespace and extract `fx:id` values from it. I’ve never seen it used like that and don’t know where you got that idea from.  Without actually loading the fxml, the loader won’t create nodes.

Comment: Besides the fact you shouldn't be using `lookup` like this, the way you call that method is weird (and note `lookup` is not related to FXML). You have arguments like `"#Nom" + fxid`. That's not how `lookup` works; it takes a CSS selector. So, I would assume the argument should just be `"#Nom"`. Unless you really have something like `<Label fx:id="nomLabel" id="NomnomLabel"/>` in your FXML file, which would be odd on its own.